# es6 как я могу проверить есть ли значение в массиве?

Tags: if, ecmascript-6

es6 как я могу проверить есть ли значение в массиве  используя синтаксис развертывания ?

```
ar = [1,2,3]
if(...ar === 2) console.log('yes')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь `[1,2,3] === 2`. Массивы имеют метод `includes`, который проверяет наличие элемента в массиве:

```
console.log([...ar].includes(2))
```

Comment: ar.includes(2) так вроде короче, зачем тут spread syntax?

Comment: @Ordman, в условии было *используя синтаксис развертывания*. Но я с вами согласен